# How can I decrypt traffic on a WEP encrypted network?

Tags: encryption, passwords, wifi, sniffer, kali-linux

Let's say that I am connected to a WEP Access Point and I want to sniff all wireless traffic inside that network. How can I decrypt the traffic even though I don't have the cryptographic key?

I found a link that shows how to decrypt live wireless traffic on WEP AP's. 
http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/linux/crack-wep-key-and-decrypt-live-traffic.html

Edit Cont.: Ok there is extreme confusion. I will explain this once more.

1. I am connected on a WEP Access Point.
2. I know the WEP key to the wireless network (Hence, that is why I am connected).
3. I want to inspect the wireless traffic but it is encrypted.
4. I want the traffic to be decrypted.
5. I do not have the cryptographic key.

I don't know where all of the confusion is coming from so I'm going to ask this.

Is the cryptographic key the same as the key that I used to log in to my WEP AP? (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx)

Comment: please reword your question to detail what it is you are trying to do. Are you just looking for a howto on WEP decryption? or on how to use wireshark?

Comment: how to on WEP decryption. Sorry for not making it clear

Comment: reopened for you - I think the links in @DW's answer have most of what you need

Comment: Backtrack, it looks to me like you already answered your own question.  It looks like the link you provided in your question answers the question.  Did you try it?  Did it work for you?  What additional information are you missing?

Comment: I just edited my question.
I will try this today and give feedback on it regarding if it works

Comment: @Backtrack, see instructions for using Wireshark to decrypt WEP traffic; it also gives examples of what a WEP key looks like.  If that was not successful for you, your best bet may be to (like the FAQ suggests) make sure your question describes in detail what you tried and what results it produced.  Or, you could try asking on Wireshark support forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WEP and WPA are different, so I will assume you are asking about WEP.  (Ask a separate question if you want to know about WPA.)

Wireshark should be able to decrypt WEP traffic if you have the cryptographic WEP key.  For instance, [here are instructions for decrypting WEP and WPA traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11).

So all that is needed is a way to find the WEP key.  There are several ways to do it:

1. If you are connected to the WEP network, then your laptop must have the WEP key.  So all you need to do is extract it.  The way to do this will be OS-dependent, so if this is what you want to know, ask a separate question about how retrieve the WEP key for a wireless network you are connected to, and specify the OS.  (e.g., on Linux, `iwconfig` will show you the WEP key.)
2. If you are not connected to the WEP network, but want to find the WEP key anyway, there are tools to do this by eavesdropping on a bunch of traffic.  I recommend [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) (see [this tutorial on aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=simple_wep_crack)).  Here is a [tutorial on using aircrack-ng with Backtrack to recover a WEP key](http://lifehacker.com/5305094/how-to-crack-a-wi+fi-networks-wep-password-with-backtrack).  Or, you could use the link you provided.

**WARNING WARNING WARNING**: Do not do this without authorization of the owner of the wireless network.  Hacking other people's wireless networks without their consent is highly illegal in most countries.  Don't do it!

---

Old information from the previous iteration of the question (you can ignore this):

For WEP, if you only have the password and not the cryptographic key, then you will need to recompute the crypto key from the password.  It is computed as a deterministic function, and if you Google for WEP key converter or WEP key calculator you should be able to find utilities that will do the conversion for you.  Or, you can just go to your access point's web configuration, and it will usually tell the WEP key (indeed, you could enter in a new passphrase and see the resulting WEP key).

For WPA, you may need to capture the traffic associated with the initial association between the client and the access point (if you just come in later and capture it after the client has already connected to the access point, you may not be able to decrypt).

Comment: Ok lets say the network is a WEP encryption 
What password? 
The password that I used to log in to their network?

Comment: What if I don't have the passwords to decrypt it? Considering someone is doing it Illegaly
Is it impossible if I don't have the key?

Comment: @Backtrack, I'm confused.  In your question, you said "I have the password".  Your latest comments says "What if I don't have the passwords?".  This sounds contradictory to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: P.S. @Backtrack, If you are asking whether it is possible to decrypt wireless traffic without knowing the cryptographic key or password, that's a separate question, and you should ask it separately (make sure to use search first to see if it has been asked before).  The short answer is: yes for some kinds of wireless networks, no for others.

Comment: @DW Yes that is my question. I want to know if I am able to decrypt wireless traffic of a WEP encrypted AP without knowing the cryptographic key

Comment: @Backtrack, OK, that's fine -- but as I said, please ask a separate question for that, or edit your question, because that's not what you wrote in the original question above.  Please use search first, as I suspect this question has been answered before.

Comment: @DW Yes I already edited my question. 
What's your feedback on the link?

Comment: @Backtrack - I don't see that question...I see some other question asking if its possible..with the password..but not without it'

Comment: This is the link I'm talking about. I edited my post and added this link. Tell me what you think . http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/linux/crack-wep-key-and-decrypt-live-traffic.html

Comment: @Backtrack, Let me back up.  It sounds like you might not be familiar with the conventions on this site.  Can I encourage you to read [the faq](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq)?  Then, please revise your question to reflect your exact question.  As it stands, your question is contradictory: your question says you have the password, your later comments say you don't.  Note: This is not a discussion forum; we rely upon well-crafted, precise questions.  I suggest you go back and re-write your question from scratch, making sure to be precise and include all assumptions.

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: I got to the last part of the link where it says decrypt live traffic in real time and everything was working except for the last command when I opened the second shell. I typed in "tcpdump -i at0" but it said "tcpdump that device is not up". What device is it referring to? And how do I put it up?

Comment: @D.W. how do you get iwconfig to display the network key? mine on Ubuntu 11.10 shows everything except the key. we're on WPA enc. security though.

Comment: How can I decrypt WEP packets in tshark like Wireshark?

Comment: @SuB, you should ask that as a separate question.